# SQL: Showing column name of calculated result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am calculating the max of a series of column and I was wondering what the best way to show the name of the result column.

Example Table:

```
hour1      hour2      hour3
16         10         5
```

My query looks like this:

```
(SELECT Max(v) 
 FROM (VALUES (hour1) , (hour2) , (hour3)) 
 AS VALUE (v)) AS PEAK_VALUE
```

Note this is in another query.

Desired output:

```
PEAK_VALUE      PEAK_HOUR
16              hour1
```

I would also like to do further calculations on the PEAK_VALUE column as well. For example dividing it by 2 for this output:

```
PEAK_VALUE     HALF_VALUE  PEAK_HOUR
16             8          hour1
```

Comment: Only one row ?  If multiple rows what would be the desired result if row 2 had 16 in hour2?

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it though you have some issue with your query syntax. You need to add the column name to the un-pivot. After that user `row_number()` to find the max value

---

```
SELECT PEAK_VALUE = v,
       HALF_VALUE = v / 2,
       PEAK_HOUR = c
FROM
(
    SELECT *, rn = row_number() over (order by v desc)
    FROM   example
           CROSS APPLY
           (
               VALUES ('hour1', hour1) , ('hour2', hour2) , ('hour3', hour3)
           )  AS VALUE (c, v)
 ) v
 WHERE rn = 1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6fffde94272d98ff9f659ee5e5da9368)

Answer (score 2):

Just another option sans row_number()

**Example**

```
Select top 1
       Peak_Value = Hour
      ,Half_Value = Hour/2
      ,Peak_Hour  = Item
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('hour1',hour1)
                    ,('hour2',hour2)
                    ,('hour3',hour3)
             ) B (Item,Hour)
 Order by Hour Desc
```

**Results**

```
Peak_Value  Half_Value  Peak_Hour
16          8           hour1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using UNPIVOT.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(hour1 int, hour2 int, hour3 int)

insert into @table
values(16,10,5)

SELECT top 1 max(val) as peak_value, max(val) /2 as Half_Value, [hour]
FROM @table
unpivot (val for [hour] in ([hour1],[hour2],[hour3])) as t
group by [hour]
order by max(val) desc
```

| peak_value | Half_Value | hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 8 | hour1 |

Answer (score 0):

**You can shove a whole unpivoting query inside a `CROSS APPLY`, and then do further calculations:**

```sql
SELECT t.*, v.*
FROM yourTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
        v.PEAK_VALUE,
        HALF_VALUE = v.PEAK_VALUE / 2,
        v.PEAK_HOUR,
    FROM (VALUES
        ('hour1', hour1),
        ('hour2', hour2),
        ('hour3', hour3)
    ) AS v(PEAK_HOUR, PEAK_VALUE)
    ORDER BY PEAK_VALUE DESC
) AS v
```

This is slightly different from the other answers, in that it will calculate the subquery *per row*